# Unable to get simple C code completion to work in linux on multiple IDEs

Tags: c, ubuntu-14.04, qt-creator, codeblocks, eclipse-cdt

I'm trying to find an IDE on linux that will support code completion. For instance in Visual studio for a C project when I do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

and then start typing "printf" a box will pop up with printf prototypes. I've been trying desperately to get this functionality in a linux ide and have tried several.

Codeblocks: on ubuntu 14.04 I've tried both 13.12 as well as installing 16.01. After putting in #include  neither will popup a dialog. "pri" will popup private as a selection only. I've tried enabling and disabling the completion plugin to no avail. And using the hot keys for calltips.

Qt-Creator: vs 3.0.1 that is installed from the ubuntu repos. #include  does not popup a printf. I've ensured in the menu settings that completion in the editor is enabled.

Eclise mars: this was a beast to install and get running. I installed it with the C/C++ development mode. I can't find any significant menu settings for code completion but I did ensure that /usr/include (where stdio.h is) is in the include paths. The header files also pop up in a lowerleft box with little locks on them and I can open it after the include statement, but it certainly does not bring up a box with "printf" in it after typing printf...

I've got some functionality of code completion in Atom (from atom.io) after installing clang and a clang-completion plugin. But it frequently crashses :/

Does anyone know how to either get codecompletion where a simple #include will open the header and allow a calltip/code hint/etc box to pop up with the function prototype on any of the above IDEs? or is this not what they mean by "autocompletion". Or do you know of a good ide that would support the functionality I'm seeking specifically?

thanks, I appreciate the help immensely!

EDIT: in response to Ashish and for clarification this is the behavior I am looking for in VS but what's happening in codeblocks. The current codeblocks version I have is 16.01 installed from the ppa "ppa:damien-moore/codeblocks" but the same issue was happening from the original codeblocks i got from "sudo apt-get install codeblocks"
[image: visual c completion]

and this is what's happening in code::blocks (as well as eclipse, and qt-creator.) it works a little but doesn't actually seem to parse the included header file...>

[image: codeblocks c completion]

Comment: KDevelop works more or less predictably. But this question is rather opinion-based,

Comment: But also you could try vim with clang plugin

Comment: @user3159253 "_Does anyone know how to either get codecompletion where a simple #include will open the header and allow a calltip/code hint/etc box to pop up with the function prototype on any of the above IDEs?_" is on-topic. Only the "_do you know of a good ide that would support the functionality I'm seeking specifically?_" part is off-topic.

Comment: Well, you know, in all popular IDEs code completion systems miserably fail from time to time. But since those IDEs behave differently in different situations, there's no true winner, all judgements will be personal, highly dependent on personal experience and personal habits. Perhaps, those having code comletion systems based on libclang, and thus _really_ parsing the code in question, those will be slightly better in most situations, but, again, this depends on particular use-cases

Comment: how about Netbeans IDE for c/c++  ??

Comment: Hrm...doesn't seem to work in KDevelop either *sigh* will try netbeans and let you know. Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: From the screen shot, it looks like you have code::blocks in C++ mode rather than C mode, so it is giving you C++ completions...

Comment: Hey Chris, thanks for the reply. That's what I thought too. But I selected "C project" during the wizard. And furthermore, even if it were C++, shouldn't it find <stdio.h> and parse it correctly?

Comment: Eclipse requires you to press a key combination (configurable, defaults to Ctrl+Space) to get completions in the middle of an identifier (as opposed to after punctuation like '.' or '::' where by default it's activated automatically).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well. I couldn't get code::blocks to work, but I finally figured out Qt-creator (phew...was starting to consider going back to visual studio :/)

The issue for Qt-creator at least was that the desktop kit by default found my Clang compiler automatically but didn't select it in the desktop kit.

Under the menu: Tools|Options|Build & Run|Kits tab|Desktop (default) and selected the compiler from the pulldown box.

Code completion is working again.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, if I'm special, but the drop down menu feature is working for me in Code::Blocks 13.12. I work in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

I think you're having a bit of a confusion. First you need to type a few words, of the function you're calling, and then the list will appear. It is highly unlikely that by typing 1 letter, you'll get all the variations.

For example, when I type only `#i` in codeblocks, nothing appears:

[image]

But when I enter `#in`, the list appears. Sorry, but I can't show the image of the list, as as soon as I click on Shutter to capture an image, it disappears. But here is what all appears on the list, after typing `#in`:

```
#define
#elif
#elifdef
#eliffndef
#else
#endif
#error
#if
#ifdef
#ifndef
#include
#line
#pragma
#undef
```

and `#include` is highlighted, as it is the only option which starts from `#in`.

I don't think there will be a difference between my Codeblocks 13.12, and yours especially because we're working on the same OS. I think you should download from the official website. But it is much simpler to install using command line itself.

Please note that you will not get an IDE in which by typing 1 or 2 letters, a dropdown list will appear. You need to type a few letters, for the drop-down list to appear.

> After putting in #include neither will popup a dialog.

Yes, it is not expected to come. `#include` is a complete keyword, and thus, there will be no more drop-down lists. If you expect a drop-down list to appear for the file you want to include, you need to type the starting. Like:

```
#include <std
```

and then it will appear. This is because, you might even be including your local file, like:

```
#include "test.h"
```

which the IDE doesn't know.

> "pri" will popup private as a selection only.

That's another weird problem. Can you please provide more information, like from where have you downloaded or installed your Code Blocks? Because that doesn't happen to me. I see:

```
printf(): int
priority_queue
private
```

Comment: "Works for me" is not an answer.

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis: I know that, but I can understand why the OP's codeblocks isn't working. It is clearly understood from his question. The user expects drop-down menus to come when they will not come. I've explained that. And why they will not come. For example the first quote from the question, the one in yellow.

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis: And by the way, codeblocks isn't a non-standard IDE.  If one is working on the same OS as the other, and on the same version, they have to be the same. I work on the same OS, and have the same version. That surely means that it is going to be the same for the OP. Just that he is not doing it properly.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11951812)

Comment: @Sнаđошƒаӽ: I don't understand your point. this isn't a clarification; I'm informing the user why his IDE is not working.

Comment: I am afraid you are *not* informing the user why his IDE is not working, rather you are informing the user that your IDE is working. Don't you think there is a difference between the two? Also the OP's problem is not just confined to CodeBlocks.

Comment: @Sнаđошƒаӽ: Have you even read the whole post? At first I tell my IDE is working, but afterwards I explain why the OP's IDE must not be working.  The problem of the user is _also_ confined to codeblocks. For example, if a question has more than one question inside it, answering only one of the questions inside the question is valid. That is what I'm doing.

Comment: Yes, I did read your whole post. Still I can't agree with you. I still consider this as "Works for me" type answer, as @MichaelFoukarakis said. And relax, the *community* will decide what's best, so chill.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I edited my post above to show you, Ashish, what the issue is. I'm sorry I wasn't clear #inc will popup a "#include" completion box. But what it won't do is parse that included header file. I don't actually get a list of functions I've included from the standard library. I installed the original codeblocks through "sudo apt-get install codeblocks" from the standard ubuntu repo. That had the same issue so I changed it to the damien moore ppa provided by codeblocks site and installed 16.01. Same issue.